# Modify field value selected from a select field

Tags: php, mysql

as part of my project I have two files:

1. modify_brand.php (php form)
2. update_brand.php (script to update the DB)

In File 1. the brands are listed in a select field and displayed in a separated field that allows to modify the brand's name.
The file 2. contains the query that update the DB.

The problem consists of passing the ID of the selected brand to the UPDATE query stored in update_brand.php in order to identify the record to update.

May be I am approaching the matter in a wrong way, but if not do you know how to pass to the query the ID?

**modify_brand.php**

```
<form role="form" action='../php/update_brand.php' method='post'>
<label>BRANDS LIST</label>

<select name='brands-list'>

<?php 
while ($listabrand=mysqli_fetch_array($brands)){
echo '<option value="'.$listabrand['1'].'">'.$listabrand['0'].' - '.$listabrand['1'].'</option>';
}?>
</select>

<label>BRAND'S NAME TO MODIFY</label>
<input type="text" name='brand-name'>  

<button type="submit" name='modify-btn' class="btn btn-default">Modifica</button>
</form>
.....   
<script>
$('select[name="brands-list"]').change(function(){  
var selectedBrand = $(this).val();
$('input[name="brand-name"]').val(selectedBrand);
});
</script>
```

**update_brand.php**

```
<?php
require '../sys/conn.php';
$mod_brand=$_POST['brand-name']

if (isset($_POST['modify-btn'])){
$brand=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $mod_brand] );

if ($mod_brand !=''){
    $update = mysqli_query($conn,"
    UPDATE mg_terms SET name= $brand 
    WHERE term_id=......... // THIS IS WHERE THE ID OF SELECTED BRAND SHOULD BE PLACED
    ");
     header('Location: ../pages/success.html');}
     else{header('Location: ../pages/error.html');}}
       mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Hope I was enoughly clear.

Comment: It seems like your input value will be same as select dropdown value after change and which is an ID of list (jquery), now input and select dropdowns value are same. So might be  mod_brand is the one which you are looking for.

Comment: A (;) is missing at the RHS of mod_brand. Ln3 of update_brand.php

Comment: Priya sorry but I am not sure I can follow you. Could you be clearer? :)

Comment: the jquery is for displaying the selected brand name into the field 'brand-name'. Select Dropdowns value and input are the same but the input value can change and modifications should be stored into db.

Comment: Then in that case while looping you are ignoring actual id of the selected brand.

Comment: Option value should be the brand id. While populating the brand name you can always do a ('option[value="'+selectedBrand+'"]').text()

Comment: So should I embed  $listabrand['0'] in the select value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152185/discussion-between-priya-and-alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do is to set the select options value to the id, So when you submit your form, the selected id is submitted to the php. But you're gonna have to change your Javascript a bit. It should set the input's value to the options text, not the options value:

```
<form role="form" action='../php/update_brand.php' method='post'>
<label>BRANDS LIST</label>

<select name='brands-list'>

<?php 
while ($listabrand=mysqli_fetch_array($brands)){
echo '<option value="'.$listabrand['0'].'">'.$listabrand['0'].' - '.$listabrand['1'].'</option>';
}?>
</select>

<label>BRAND'S NAME TO MODIFY</label>
<input type="text" name='brand-name'>  

<button type="submit" name='modify-btn' class="btn btn-default">Modifica</button>
</form>
.....   
<script>
$('select[name="brands-list"]').change(function(){  
$('input[name="brand-name"]').val($('select[name="brands-list"] option:selected').text().split(' - ')[1]);
});
</script>
```

And on the php side:

```
<?php
require '../sys/conn.php';
$mod_brand=$_POST['brand-name'];
$mod_id=$_POST['brands-list'];

if (isset($_POST['modify-btn'])){
$brand=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $mod_brand );
$brand_id=intval($mod_id );

if ($mod_brand !=''){
    $update = mysqli_query($conn,"
    UPDATE mg_terms SET name= '$brand' 
    WHERE term_id=$brand_id
    ");
     header('Location: ../pages/success.html');}
     else{header('Location: ../pages/error.html');}}
       mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: Manuel I am going to implement the code accordingly. Come up with result soon

Comment: Manuel it doesn't work. 1) Selecting the brand from the list it is not shown in the brand-name field. However even if I select the brand and fill in the brand-name the change is not done. Here the implemented code: https://pastebin.com/mUYwqYGH

Comment: Oh, sorry, it had a typo. Please check it now. (wrote 'brand-list' instead of 'brands-list')

Comment: I already did that change but nothing. Please could you have a look to the implemented version of code in the pastebin link posted in my previous comment?

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 19 - please refer to my post. Also on line 29 you're still using 'brand-list' with out 's'. Is the brand id stored as a integer or string in your database?

Comment: Manuel I corrected the syntax error and now the brand is displayed in the field in this way:  http://imgur.com/odnPnRR , however I can't find "brand-list" field since  I used only "brands-list" name. To this link find the code I am using now: https://pastebin.com/5848U3db

Comment: updated my post once again. Now it should only copy the brand name into the input. does the updating on the database work?

Comment: Hi Manuel, yes indeed the brand name is displayed correctly: http://imgur.com/a/Y5ixG

Comment: The problem is on the update process. Changing the brand's name it gives only a blank page and any change on the database is made. Something wrong in the update_brand.php file.

Comment: I removed the sanitize check intval and changed the query WHERE term_id='$mod_id' but without success

Comment: Manuel I simplified the script: https://pastebin.com/nwh4duR2t in order to check what was wrong and it looks like it doesn't read the variables values because any echo is generated.

Comment: Manuel I made another attempt removing '' from the value 0 of the array, but nothing. please have a look:  https://pastebin.com/PQt5wXGx

Comment: Debugging the execution of update_brand.php file, it gives this error:   Notice: Undefined index: brands-list in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gest/php/update_brand.php on line 4
Notice: Undefined index: brand-name in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gest/php/update_brand.php on line 5

Comment: does echoing $mod_brand and $mod_id output the correct values?

Comment: No Manuel it gaves the error reported in my previous post. However I am attempting another approach, adding in the form two fields: brand-id and brand-name. Please could you modify the js in order to display the selected value from the list splitted in those two fields?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152275/discussion-between-manuel-otto-and-alex).